# Certain option not showing in layered navigation in Magento 2.2.6?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I am running a **Magento 2.2.6** store. I have an attribute called `max-size`. Now when I navigate to a category page, it does not show all possible options represented by the products shown in the category.

One product, for example, has `200` as `max-size` but that's not shown in the filter. Other values are shown, so the attribute can be filtered, it just misses some of the filter options.

I rebuild the index using `bin/magento indexer:reindex` and also cleaned the cache, did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about on a simple or configurable product? if configurable i can confirm that this is a bug with magento and has previously been reported

Comment: Please check the atttribute configuration under Store -> Product, May be that attribute is not selected for layered navogation.
or Secondly, may be you don't have products with value of those attributes that's why layered navigation is not showing you options.

Comment: @Himani: Some filters from the attribute are shown, so thats not the problem.

Comment: @Dava: Yes, its a configurable product ... is there a fix available maybe?

Comment: I reported this in 2.2 and as far as i can see no but i will find and bump it and post a link here so you can keep a look out

Comment: Try to remove generated folder, then run update, and reindex may be then it will work. @Arnie